# Как правильно настроить postgresql django

Tags: django, postgresql

Выложил проект на хостинг, работают все страницы кроме тех, где используется БД для отображения контента. На локальном сервере все работает нормально через postgresql, но на хостинге 500 ошибка.И файл БД с расширением sqlite3.

Фрагмент настроек

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли указать HOST и Port, где находится база данных:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'myproject',
    'USER': 'myprojectuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
  }
}
```

[Больше инфы](https://timeweb.com/ru/community/articles/kak-ispolzovat-postgresql-c-prilozheniem-django-na-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

В консоле:
`pip install psycopg2`

В файле settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    ...
}
```